# How to handle load balancing in Microsoft Azure

Tags: android, azure

I am using Microsoft Azure.i want know how Microsoft Azure handle traffic at Server.
weather I write any code for handling traffic or Microsoft Azure handle server traffic itself.
Please help me.

Comment: i am new to android ..i am integrating my app with Microsoft Azure Mobile Service . i am doing this first time ..i don't know how to use Microsoft Azure Mobile service. i need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

azure has feature of load balancing for its data traffic. for that purpose a traffic manager is used.

A traffic manager profile has to be created to enable that feature
link : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/

hope this will help you